# what is dlclose() doing when it hangs?

Tags: c++, debugging, aix, freeze, callstack

```
0x0900000000054be4  unatexit(??) + 0x64
0x090000017026bad8  __sterm80000000_x_2fhome_2fMbuilder_2fviews_2fMbuilder_5f10_2e2_2drel_5fview2_2fKernel_2fSourceCode_2fDSSCommandsAll_2fLogoutUserFromProject_2fLogoutUserFromProject_2ecpp()() + 0x2f98
0x09000000008b9a80  __catchThrownException() + 0x60
0x09000000000e3ce0  terminate_one_library(??, ??) + 0x120
0x09000000000e35b0  terminate_libs(??, ??) + 0x190
0x09000000000e1e08  unload_libs(??) + 0x328
0x09000000000e539c  terminateAndUnload(??) + 0x3c
0x090000000008b020  dlclose(??) + 0x2e0
0x090000000c0a798c  MBase::SharedLibraryImpl::~SharedLibraryImpl()(0x110030710, 0x300000003, 0x9001000a0f2a360) + 0x10c
0x00000001000619d8  MBase::StrongBase<MBase::SharedLibrary*,MBase::DeleteC<MBase::SharedLibrary> >::~StrongBase()(??, ??) + 0x58
0x000000010006051c  MBase::StrongPtr<MBase::SharedLibrary,MBase::DeleteC<MBase::SharedLibrary> >::~StrongPtr()(??, ??) + 0x1c
0x0000000100062bac  MExec::Controller_Impl::~Controller_Impl()(??, ??, ??) + 0x6c
0x0000000100003600  MExec::Main(int,const char**)(??, ??) + 0xec0
0x0000000100000d8c  main(??, ??) + 0xac
0x0000000100000620  __start() + 0x98
```

What's the method `ecpp()()` in the second line? I cannot understand the method because the compiler generated the method.

background:
When my application hangs, I use `procstack` command to get the call stack on AIX   machine. And `dlclose()` cost long time.

Thanks @ZsigmondLőrinczy . if the method ecpp()() is a destructor generated by compiler, is there any debug skill that help to see why the application hang ? Because the method in the second line changes everytime I use porcstack command. So I cannot make sure which destructor cost very long time.

Comment: That looks like a C++ mangled name, and `ecpp()` is probably just a boilerplate suffix that identifies the language implementation.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

Comment: You seem to either terminating your application, or calling `dlclose` on a shared library. In both case a function called `destructor` is running, which can do whatever it feels like. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html

Comment: Looks like it's a generated name with the full path of the function's defining file encoded (2f is '/', 2e is '.'): `/home/Mbuilder/views/Mbuilder[...]/LogoutUserFromProject.cpp`

Comment: You might choose to never call `dlclose` in particular when your program is only dynamically loading a few dozens of plugins.

Comment: Thanks @ZsigmondLőrinczy . if the method ecpp()() is a destructor generated by compiler, is there any debug skill that help to see why the application hang ? Because the method in the second line changes everytime I use porcstack command. So I cannot make sure which destructor cost very long time.

Comment: Debugging is hard, but debugging C++ is nearly impossible. truss(1) might help...
Also it should be checked that the different parts (main executable and the shared libraries) were compiled with the same compiler settings. (see here: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0002)